# Difference between i++ and i = i+1 in terms of atomicity

Tags: java, thread-safety, atomic

I know that i++ is not a thread safe operation. I also understand why i++ is faster than i = i+1 also. Is i = i+1 any different from i++ in terms of thread safety? Any bytecode level explanation would be really helpful.

Comment: They compile to [identical bytecode](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=G6Hadz8Q), so they should have the same performance.

Comment: @August2 - Nice.  You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Neither `i += 1` nor `i++` is atomic (neither is thread safe). The same goes for `++i`. Here's a simple test you can run to prove this:

```
public class Test {

    static volatile int x, y;

     static class IncThread extends Thread {
         public void run() {
            for (int i=0; i<50000; i++) x++;
            for (int i=0; i<50000; i++) y = y+1;
         }
     }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread t1 = new IncThread();
        Thread t2 = new IncThread();
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t1.join();
        t2.join();
        System.out.printf("x = %d, y = %d%n", x, y);
    }

}
```

Here's what I get for output:

```
x = 99897, y = 81556
```

Obviously, some of the writes got lost. There's a nice little blog post, [++ not considered atomic](http://madbean.com/2003/mb2003-44/), that explains this. That post also points out that @August's answer is misleading. That bytecode (`iinc`) is only generated for incrementing *local variables*, which are not interesting from the perspective of thread-safety. (The blog post also talks about the different bytecodes used for increments.)

Comment: If you have an issue with August's answer, you should put a comment under that answer, and possibly a downvote.  Someone might use that answer, and not even see yours.

Answer (score 6):

There is no difference between `i++` and `i += 1`, bytecode-wise:

**Increment** (Source):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i = 0;
    i++;
}
```

**Increment** (Bytecode):

```
public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: iconst_0      
       1: istore_1      
       2: iinc          1, 1
       5: return
```

---

**Compound addition** (Source):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i = 0;
    i += 1;
}
```

**Compound addition** (Bytecode):

```
public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: iconst_0      
       1: istore_1      
       2: iinc          1, 1
       5: return
```

The bytecode used for incrementing fields is also the same, although it doesn't use the `iinc` instruction (because it would need a local variable index):

```
int x;

void inc() { x++; }
void assign() { x += 1; }
```

---

```
void inc();
    Code:
       0: aload_0       
       1: dup           
       2: getfield      #2                  // Field x:I
       5: iconst_1      
       6: iadd          
       7: putfield      #2                  // Field x:I
      10: return        

  void assign();
    Code:
       0: aload_0       
       1: dup           
       2: getfield      #2                  // Field x:I
       5: iconst_1      
       6: iadd          
       7: putfield      #2                  // Field x:I
      10: return
```

Comment: How do you go about reading the bytecode from a compiled source?

Comment: @DavidJones You can use `javap -c Foo.class` (or my rather crappy [website](http://bytes.i-i.im/))

Comment: You should edit your answer to point out that the `iinc` instruction is only generated to increment _local_ variables. See [++ not considered atomic](http://madbean.com/2003/mb2003-44/) for some examples.

Answer (score 1):

`i=i+1` uses a binary operator (+) which loads the value of i, and adds one to it, and then store the result back to i. In contrast, `i++` uses the unary (++) operator which simply increments the value using a single assembly instruction, so in theory it could be more efficient. However, with today's compilers optimization `i=i+1` and `i++` will result in the same optimized code.

Answer (score -1):

There is no differences between i++ and i=i+1 in those terms.

Comment: please check these one to understand difference http://stackoverflow.com/a/29559727/4025692