# Difference Between i = i+1 & i++

Tags: java, casting, operators

Can anyone solve my confusion here is my code :

```
byte i = 0;

i++;
System.out.println(i);
```

Result: ***1***

```
byte i = 0;

i = i+1;
System.out.println(i);
```

Generate compile time error: ***Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to byte***

When I convert that to byte like:   ***`i = (byte) (i+1);`*** then happily getting result ***1***

Performing this example i am understand i = i+1 & i++ perform can't same opearation so now i want to know what is exactally difference between them ...!!!

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13100019/why-can-not-i-add-two-bytes-and-get-an-int-and-i-can-add-two-final-bytes-get-a-b

Comment: implicit casting happens while doing increment.. so both are same at the end.

Comment: I think you should focus your learning on the differences between the primitive data types **byte** and **int** - and the conversions between those.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Finally i am found my problems(questions) superior understand so here describe it to understands others easily..!!!

1> **i = i + 1**

In java whenever any arithmetic operation performs between two or more variables then it's return value's type depends upon like this equation :

> RETURN VALUE TYPE = (int, MAXIMUM RANGE OF VARIABLE-1, MAXIMUM RANGE
>   OF VARIABLE-N )

here, Return value type : **int**

For eqution *(int, byte, byte)* so int have maximum range..

*byte -> 1 byte size &
int -> 4 byte size*

That's why above exe i can't store that return value in byte directly it's require **external type casting**  *i = (byte) (i+1)*

2> **i++**

In java whenever increment & decrement operation perform like these then it's return value's type depends upon this equation:

> RETURN VALUE TYPE = (VARIABLE TYPE, VALUE + 1)

these equation denote **internal type casting** perform in this case

**MUST REMEMBER:**

***case 1***: *External type cast require if needed*

***case 2***: *internal type casting perform automatically*

Answer (score 6):

`i++` and `i+=1` implicitly cast the result back to the type of `i`.

So if `i` is a `byte`, then `i++;` is *not* equivalent to `i = i + 1;` - it's actually equivalent to `i = (byte)(i + 1);`.

From the Java Language Specification, [section 15.14.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.14.2), emphasis mine:

> ... the value 1 is added to the value of the variable and the sum is stored back into the variable. Before the addition, binary numeric promotion (§5.6.2) is performed on the value 1 and the value of the variable. **If necessary, the sum is narrowed by a narrowing primitive conversion (§5.1.3)** and/or subjected to boxing conversion (§5.1.7) **to the type of the variable before it is stored**.

There's no fundamental reason to it, other than "because the specification says so". The people who wrote the specification most likely wrote it this way so that `++` would be useful for all numeric types (not just `int` and `long`).

Comment: @DhruvRaval Do you know the difference between `i = i + 1` and `i = (byte)(i + 1)`?

Answer (score 2):

internally for **short, char, byte and int** datatype if any arithmetic operation is performed compiler will upgrade data type to **int** and perform the operation. compiler will change the data type of expression result value to **int**

so for byte i

```
i = i+1; // will not work
```

because `i+1` will result an integer data type value. so you have to typecast externally as

```
i = (byte)(i+1); // this is equivalent to i +=1; or you can say i++;
```

Comment: @Jägermeister : dude add two byte values and assign in byte variable and see.

Comment: @Jägermeister No, *that's* not true. The result of adding two `byte`s is an `int`, [try it and see](http://ideone.com/D4WzNI).

Comment: @Jägermeister : as per you `byte b=0;byte c=0; byte d=b+c;` this should work?? but it will not work because the result is an int.

Comment: @Jägermeister this is called binary numeric promotion: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2

Comment: I think it's because you missed the brackets. `i = (byte)(i + 1)`;